# How to use ListView from ListFragment?

Tags: android, listview, fragment, android-listfragment

```html
public class sidebar extends ListFragment{
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
ArrayList<String> pavan = new ArrayList<String>();
pavan.add("Short Transmission Lines");
pavan.add("Medium pi Transmission Lines");
pavan.add("Medium T Transmission Lines");
pavan.add("Long Transmission Lines");
ca kumar = new ca(getActivity(), 0, pavan);
setListAdapter(kumar);}}
```

I am dealing with List Fragments. I have used `setContentView(Listview)` without creating other layout files for an activity and used activities listview. How could I do same with List fragments without using other xml layouts and only using List View of List `Fragment.setContentView` and returning listview simply seems to be not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
public class ListViewDemoFragment extends ListFragment {
    
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setListAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

sample is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20141007015417/http://www.perfectapk.com/android-listfragment-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setListAdapter(mAdapter);`

to get listView object, you can do like below:

```
ListView mListView = getListView();
```